# Symfony session array works fine in controller but not in twig

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, session, twig

I have an array called `$products` and I am assigng that to symfony session.

**ARRAY**

```
Array
(
    [services] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [icon] => bus.png
                    [name] => Web Development
                    [cost] => 500
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [icon] => ok-shield.png
                    [name] => Saadia
                    [cost] => 200
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [icon] => car.png
                    [name] => Web Development 2
                    [cost] => 200
                )

        )

)
```

This is how I am assigning it to session

```
$session = $request->getSession();
$session->set('products', array('services' => $products));
```

Now, if I access this session in `twig` using `{{ dump(app.session.get('products')) }}` I can view and access it perfectly fine.

[image]

These session values are actually used in a shopping cart that has a delete link next to each product and if you click on the delete link that specific product should get removed from session array so to achieve this I am using a delete route that calls the following function to remove that part of the array and reassign updated array to same session variable

```
public function CartRemoveAction($id, Request $request){
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $products = $session->get('products');
    foreach($products['services'] as $key => $service)
    {
        if($service['id'] == $id)
        {
            unset($products['services'][$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
    $session->set('products', array(
        'services' => $products,
    ));
    return $this->render('featureBundle:Default:cart.html.twig');
}
```

But this leaves me with 2 services array in twig.

[image]

Even if I remove the session and reassign it, I end up with the same problem.
I am using the following code to remove `products` array from session.
`$session->remove('products');`

What am I doing wrong which is leading to 2 arrays or services?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do `$session->set('products, $products)`? Or even `$session->set('products', array("services" => $products["services"]));`

Comment: i just tried `$session->set('products, $products)` and this fixed the problem, was stuck at this for hourssss. Would you like to add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, maybe take a break, make some tea, go for a walk.

Comment: you are correct, i need to take a break. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

```
$products = $session->get('products');
```

To set it back correctly, use:

```
$session->set('products', $products);
```